# Using 2 recaptcha on same page and getting different values for both via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I have 2 Google Recaptcha's on same page in different forms (Login and Register Forms). I had to put both the forms on the same page due to the designing requirements which can't be changed. Now the problem is that the 1st form is the login form followed by the register form in the 2nd. Now, the recaptcha on the login form takes effect for register form as well. I mean that I can see recaptcha on both the forms but the one in register form doesn't work (which means it doesn't sends the correct value to the PHP page where the form will be processed). When I tried verifying the recaptcha on the login form and submitting the register form it worked. This means that the 1st loaded recaptcha (on the login form) is working for both which should not be. Both the recaptchas should work separately for each forms. Also, when I get the values of both the recaptchas via AJAX to send to the PHP page for the server side validation I am using `captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()` for both. THIS CAN BE THE ACTUAL PROBLEM I GUESS. If I could get separate values for both maybe the things would have gone down well. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my codes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3 class="com-reps cr-panel">Login Now</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3 class="com-reps cr-panel">Register Now</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="post-holder">
        <div class="login-message"></div>
        <div class="post-content">
          <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $mainf['set_recaptcha_sitekey']; ?>"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="post-holder">
        <div class="register-message"></div>
        <div class="post-content">
          <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" id="cpass" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              Sex &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex"> Male &nbsp;
              <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex"> Female
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="checkbox" id="legal" name="legal"> &nbsp; I accept the <a href="tos.php">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a>.
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $mainf['set_recaptcha_sitekey']; ?>"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").click(function(){
    var dataString = {
      uname: $("#uname").val(),
      pass: $("#pass").val(),
      captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      //dataType : "json",
      url: "processes/login.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#login").val("Please wait...");
        $(".login-message").hide();
      },
      success: function(html){
        $('.login-message').html(html).fadeIn();
        if($('.login-message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('alert-success')){
          setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace("index.php");
          }, 500);
        }else{
          $("#login").val("Log In");
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var dataString = {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      uname: $("#username").val(),
      pass: $("#password").val(),
      cpass: $("#cpass").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      dob: $("#dob").val(),
      sex: $("input[name='sex']:checked").val(),
      captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      //dataType : "json",
      url: "processes/register.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#submit").val("Please wait...");
        $(".register-message").hide();
      },
      success: function(html){
        $('.register-message').html(html).fadeIn();
        $("#submit").val("Register");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. In case someone comes looking for this it will help them.

In both HTML Forms replace

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
```

to

`<div id="recaptcha1"></div>` and `<div id="recaptcha2"></div>` respectively.

Then replace your script calling from

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

And insert these code in your `<script></script>`. Note that this should be outside of `$(document).ready(function() {` and above your next form submission AJAX codes.

```
var recaptcha1;
var recaptcha2;
var myCallBack = function() {
  recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
    'sitekey' : 'YOUR_SITE_KEY'
  });
  recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
    'sitekey' : 'YOUR_SITE_KEY'
  });
};
```

Next and last thing, change the `captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()` in your form submission AJAX code to `captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha1)` and `captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha2)` respectively (for both AJAX codes of login and register forms in my case). For full form submission code please refer to the code in my question above. Just replace the `captcha:` part here as said.

Done! Now you can proceed to server side validation in your language (PHP or ASP whatever).